# Android Splash taking time to launch without white screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have created a splash screen with code,

Activity:

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(new MyView(Splash.this));
    }


public class MyView extends View {
        Bitmap splashBmp;
        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            try {
                int x = getHeight();
                int y = getWidth();
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                canvas.drawPaint(paint);
                splashBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.splash);
                splashBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(splashBmp, (y),(x), true);
                canvas.drawBitmap(splashBmp,0, 0, paint);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
   }


<style name="splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">false</item>
    </style>
```

AndroidManifest file:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@style/splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The problem is app always takes 3 or 4 seconds to launch splash screen(without white screen) after the launcher icon click. How to solve this??

I have tried both xml and Canvas.

Comment: `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` can take time . And what i see in `MyView` you are just drawing the image . Why don't just set it in xml ? Also make sure image is of less size in Mbs .

Comment: @ADM it still the same. In xml I create a Relativelayout and set it as background image.

Comment: `onDraw()` will call so many time and its not good to create bitmap on it
better to create bitmap and scaled one in constructor and then just draw it in `onDraw()`
also this is why your splash takes to long to launch

Answer (score 0):

**Here is most robust way to start splash with 0 second delay.**

> You have to set an theme only to your splash activity. You will set an
>   background instead of using layout on Splash Screen.

```
<activity
   android:name=".SplashActivity"
   android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
 ...
</activity>
```

> Put this style in your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_bitmap</item>
</style>
```

> Here `splash_bitmap` can be any drawable `png, jpg, or xml drawable`.
>   Here is mine you can make yours inside `res>drawable` directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I have the splash image not logo. the above code will centre crop the image. but it still have the delay